# Flutter Subscription (RevenueCat)

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an error with my subscription in my Flutter app. 
I did al the steps here https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/android-subscriptions-tutorial,

When I subscribe, it says Subscribed, and I can see my subscription on Google Play, but it says that there are some problems with Google Play Store and it wont redirect me to the next page.

Full Log :

```
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Debug logging enabled.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): SDK Version - 3.1.0
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Initial App User ID - null
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Generated New App User ID - 26c252dd759a42899cbdaca5e8f165a3
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Identifying App User ID: $RCAnonymousID:26c252dd759a42899cbdaca5e8f165a3
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): App foregrounded
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): PurchaserInfo cache is stale, updating caches
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Offerings cache is stale, updating caches
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): [QueryPurchases] Skipping updating pending purchase queue since BillingClient is not connected yet
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): No subscriber attributes to synchronize.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Subscriber attributes synced successfully.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Listener set
I/System.out(22348): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(22348): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Starting connection for com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl@b3b0036
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): No cached purchaser info, fetching
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Billing Service Setup finished for com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl@b3b0036.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): [QueryPurchases] Updating pending purchase queue
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): GET /subscribers/%24RCAnonymousID%3A26c252dd759a42899cbdaca5e8f165a3
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): GET /subscribers/%24RCAnonymousID%3A26c252dd759a42899cbdaca5e8f165a3 201
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Sending latest purchaser info to listener
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Purchaser info updated, sending to listener
I/System.out(22348): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(22348): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): No cached offerings, fetching
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): GET /subscribers/%24RCAnonymousID%3A26c252dd759a42899cbdaca5e8f165a3/offerings
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): GET /subscribers/%24RCAnonymousID%3A26c252dd759a42899cbdaca5e8f165a3/offerings 200
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Requesting products with identifiers: onemonthathlete, lifetimeathlete
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Requesting products with identifiers: onemonthathlete, lifetimeathlete
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): [QueryPurchases] Querying subs
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): [QueryPurchases] Querying inapp
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): [QueryPurchases] Cleaning previously sent tokens
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): [QueryPurchases] Tokens already posted: []
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): [QueryPurchases] Saving tokens []
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): [QueryPurchases] Tokens already posted: []
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Products request finished for onemonthathlete, lifetimeathlete
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Retrieved skuDetailsList: SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4JfHSozIDQz3ogqW5_NyfRhtNt-A-LcANvB3qrztlhuiwZwEfaGhutYbgPOxNY9","productId":"lifetimeathlete","type":"subs","price":"$126.92","price_amount_micros":126920000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1Y","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"Lifetime Access (Athlete.co)","description":"Lifetime Access"}, SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4KlDHUVcCC0ra-q73FjLFF_VHSYmVIGJshi8MT9ljIWGCLne_GojqWqwKqD-4T6","productId":"onemonthathlete","type":"subs","price":"$20.16","price_amount_micros":20160000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1M","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"One Month Access (Athlete.co)","description":"One Month access to all exercises with this subscription."}
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): lifetimeathlete - SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4JfHSozIDQz3ogqW5_NyfRhtNt-A-LcANvB3qrztlhuiwZwEfaGhutYbgPOxNY9","productId":"lifetimeathlete","type":"subs","price":"$126.92","price_amount_micros":126920000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1Y","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"Lifetime Access (Athlete.co)","description":"Lifetime Access"}
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): onemonthathlete - SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4KlDHUVcCC0ra-q73FjLFF_VHSYmVIGJshi8MT9ljIWGCLne_GojqWqwKqD-4T6","productId":"onemonthathlete","type":"subs","price":"$20.16","price_amount_micros":20160000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1M","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"One Month Access (Athlete.co)","description":"One Month access to all exercises with this subscription."}
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Products request finished for onemonthathlete, lifetimeathlete
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Retrieved skuDetailsList: SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4JfHSozIDQz3ogqW5_NyfRhtNt-A-LcANvB3qrztlhuiwZwEfaGhutYbgPOxNY9","productId":"lifetimeathlete","type":"subs","price":"$126.92","price_amount_micros":126920000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1Y","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"Lifetime Access (Athlete.co)","description":"Lifetime Access"}, SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4KlDHUVcCC0ra-q73FjLFF_VHSYmVIGJshi8MT9ljIWGCLne_GojqWqwKqD-4T6","productId":"onemonthathlete","type":"subs","price":"$20.16","price_amount_micros":20160000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1M","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"One Month Access (Athlete.co)","description":"One Month access to all exercises with this subscription."}
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): lifetimeathlete - SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4JfHSozIDQz3ogqW5_NyfRhtNt-A-LcANvB3qrztlhuiwZwEfaGhutYbgPOxNY9","productId":"lifetimeathlete","type":"subs","price":"$126.92","price_amount_micros":126920000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1Y","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"Lifetime Access (Athlete.co)","description":"Lifetime Access"}
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): onemonthathlete - SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4KlDHUVcCC0ra-q73FjLFF_VHSYmVIGJshi8MT9ljIWGCLne_GojqWqwKqD-4T6","productId":"onemonthathlete","type":"subs","price":"$20.16","price_amount_micros":20160000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1M","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"One Month Access (Athlete.co)","description":"One Month access to all exercises with this subscription."}
I/flutter (22348): Offering{identifier: default-monthly, serverDescription: Standard monthly set of packages, availablePackages: [Package{identifier: $rc_monthly, packageType: PackageType.monthly, product: Product{identifier: onemonthathlete, description: One Month access to all exercises with this subscription., title: One Month Access (Athlete.co), price: 20.16, priceString: $20.16, currencyCode: USD, introductoryPrice: IntroductoryPrice{introPrice: 0.0, introPriceString: $0.00, introPricePeriod: P1W, introPricePeriodUnit: DAY, introPricePeriodNumberOfUnits: 7, introPriceCycles: 1}}, offeringIdentifier: default-monthly}, Package{identifier: $rc_lifetime, packageType: PackageType.lifetime, product: Product{identifier: lifetimeathlete, description: Lifetime Access, title: Lifetime Access (Athlete.co), price: 126.92, priceString: $126.92, currencyCode: USD, introductoryPrice: IntroductoryPrice{introPrice: 0.0, introPriceString: $0.00, introPricePeriod: P1W, introPricePeriodUnit: DAY, introPricePeriodNumberOfUnits: 7, introPrice
I/flutter (22348): Package{identifier: $rc_monthly, packageType: PackageType.monthly, product: Product{identifier: onemonthathlete, description: One Month access to all exercises with this subscription., title: One Month Access (Athlete.co), price: 20.16, priceString: $20.16, currencyCode: USD, introductoryPrice: IntroductoryPrice{introPrice: 0.0, introPriceString: $0.00, introPricePeriod: P1W, introPricePeriodUnit: DAY, introPricePeriodNumberOfUnits: 7, introPriceCycles: 1}}, offeringIdentifier: default-monthly}OFFERING MONTHLY
D/ViewRootImpl@e0082f1[MainActivity](22348): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e0082f1[MainActivity](22348): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (22348):  u try sam usao  ++++++++++++++++++
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Vending offerings from cache
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): purchase started - product: SkuDetails: {"skuDetailsToken":"AEuhp4KlDHUVcCC0ra-q73FjLFF_VHSYmVIGJshi8MT9ljIWGCLne_GojqWqwKqD-4T6","productId":"onemonthathlete","type":"subs","price":"$20.16","price_amount_micros":20160000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1M","freeTrialPeriod":"P1W","title":"One Month Access (Athlete.co)","description":"One Month access to all exercises with this subscription."}  - offering: default-monthly
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): Making purchase for sku: onemonthathlete
W/ActivityThread(22348): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@826fc3b
D/PhoneWindow(22348): forceLight changed to true [] from com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.updateForceLightNavigationBar:4238 com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.updateColorViews:1490 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged:3216 android.view.Window.setFlags:1148 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout:2444 
I/MultiWindowDecorSupport(22348): updateCaptionType >> DecorView@49ed196[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
D/MultiWindowDecorSupport(22348): setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@49ed196[]
D/ViewRootImpl@3767eed[ProxyBillingActivity](22348): setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@49ed196 TM=true MM=false
D/ViewRootImpl@e0082f1[MainActivity](22348): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(22348): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@d561475[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(22348): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/ViewRootImpl@3767eed[ProxyBillingActivity](22348): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=7 res=0x7 s={true 499042742272} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer(22348): createReliableSurface : 0x7419580880, 0x743143f000
D/ViewRootImpl@3767eed[ProxyBillingActivity](22348): MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,1080,2400) ci=(0,76,0,126) vi=(0,76,0,126) or=1
D/InputTransport(22348): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=108
W/BillingHelper(22348): Couldn't find purchase lists, trying to find single data.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): BillingWrapper purchases updated. onemonthathlete GPA.3330-8467-4550-90881 aolipdjnbkjdnnobnccokhod.AO-J1OyCPAYXPaGJFyTmE-RtgWe8vxA8qtRkQqQWGRbJdgifLL2ZgBWNP8YVMUr7ATFbPTMZYcdpNVGiQ66irN3cXqL-gOhpoIYMRYJcYdl-HzN-x8u1VsuOEE8VyNh5mOQphC15kdFK
I/System.out(22348): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(22348): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/ViewRootImpl@3767eed[ProxyBillingActivity](22348): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(22348): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@49ed196[ProxyBillingActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(22348): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager(22348): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@49ed196[ProxyBillingActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(22348): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager(22348): Starting input: tba=com.flutter.Athlete.co ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(22348): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(22348): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/ViewRootImpl@e0082f1[MainActivity](22348): stopped(false) old=false
D/ViewRootImpl@3767eed[ProxyBillingActivity](22348): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(22348): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@49ed196[ProxyBillingActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(22348): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/ViewRootImpl@e0082f1[MainActivity](22348): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(22348): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@d561475[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(22348): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager(22348): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@d561475[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(22348): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager(22348): Starting input: tba=com.flutter.Athlete.co ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(22348): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(22348): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(22348): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=108
D/ViewRootImpl@3767eed[ProxyBillingActivity](22348): stopped(true) old=false
D/ViewRootImpl@3767eed[ProxyBillingActivity](22348): dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport(22348): Input channel destroyed: 'acb1706', fd=125
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): POST /receipts
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(22348): POST /receipts 503
E/[Purchases] - ERROR(22348): There was a problem with the Play Store. | Problem communicating with the Store when trying to validate the receipt.
```

Comment: `Problem communicating with the Store when trying to validate the receipt.` - are your service credentials set up in RevenueCat? Does this error happen every time? Maybe the Play Store had a hiccup.

Comment: yes, this error happens every time, 
I successfully get my purchases, and I even see my subscription in Google Play.
But that last step that need to verify my purchase, and show it in sandbox can't get through. 
It won't verify that my user that made purchase is pro.

Comment: Did you solve it !!@enc_life

Comment: @DanisPreldžić   did you get the solution, m facing the same issue, can you please share the solution.. Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue